# How to change row per page list

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I need to change this select options

[image]

I didn't see any props for that. How can I do it?

Comment: What's the component you are using for the drop-down?

Answer (score 1):

There is a props called `items` which can be an array of objects or array of strings. When using objects, will look for a text, value and disabled keys. This can be changed using the item-text, item-value and item-disabled props. Objects that have a header or divider property are considered special cases and generate a list header or divider; these items are not selectable.

For example you can do like

```html
<v-select :items="options" />
```

where `options` can be

```js
[ {
  text: string | number | object,
  value: string | number | object,
  disabled: boolean,
  divider: boolean,
  header: string
},
{
  text: string | number | object,
  value: string | number | object,
  disabled: boolean,
  divider: boolean,
  header: string
}]
```

Or

```js
[ '1', '2','3']
```

For more info check this out
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props-items